How to detect when camera is idle in mapbox android sdk 10
I recently migrated from Mapbox Android SDK 9 to SDK 10 and noticed that onCameraIdleListener, which was available in SDK 9, is no longer present in SDK 10. Is there an alternative or recommended approach to detect when the camera is idle (i.e., no longer moving) in SDK 10? I’d like to achieve similar functionality to onCameraIdleListener for both user-initiated gestures and programmatic camera changes
I have tried using onMapIdleListener but it gets called continously even when the camera or map is not moved

This mapbox issue comment offers a suggestion for comparable camera idle listener: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/issues/1944#issuecomment-1547691788.  The termination used is "CameraAnimation".  Requires client managing state to infer when idle - a bit wanky.
